# Looping a nesty struture in Coldfusion

Tags: json, coldfusion, structure

Here is my JSON Data:
This i am trying to loop and get all the information about every node of it with the key name and the key data

```
{
    "src": 1,
    "feeds": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "All",
        "polarPlot": true
    }],
    "srcFeed": 1,
    "showSil": true,
    "showFlg": true,
    "showPic": true,
    "flgH": 20,
    "flgW": 85,
    "acList": [{
        "Id": 12589424,
        "Rcvr": 1,
        "HasSig": false,
        "Icao": "C01970",
        "Bad": false,
        "Reg": "C-FJQL",
        "FSeen": "\/Date(1672216397120)\/",
        "TSecs": 334,
        "CMsgs": 330,
        "Alt": 34975,
        "GAlt": 35206,
        "InHg": 30.15059,
        "AltT": 0,
        "Call": "ROU1958",
        "Lat": 45.59019,
        "Long": -74.90746,
        "PosTime": 1672216731130,
        "Mlat": false,
        "Tisb": false,
        "Spd": 469.0,
        "Trak": 59.3,
        "TrkH": false,
        "Type": "A321",
        "Mdl": "Airbus A321 211SL",
        "Man": "Airbus",
        "CNum": "7117",
        "From": "YYZ Lester B. Pearson, Toronto, Canada",
        "To": "YQB Quebec Jean Lesage, Canada",
        "Op": "Air Canada Rouge",
        "OpIcao": "ROU",
        "Sqk": "2222",
        "Help": false,
        "Vsi": 0,
        "VsiT": 0,
        "WTC": 2,
        "Species": 1,
        "Engines": "2",
        "EngType": 3,
        "EngMount": 0,
        "Mil": false,
        "Cou": "Canada",
        "HasPic": false,
        "Interested": false,
        "FlightsCount": 2,
        "Gnd": false,
        "SpdTyp": 0,
        "CallSus": false,
        "Trt": 2,
        "Year": "2016"
    }, {
        "Id": 12595324,
        "Rcvr": 1,
        "HasSig": false,
        "Icao": "C0307C",
        "Bad": false,
        "Reg": "C-FSJJ",
        "FSeen": "\/Date(1672215986531)\/",
        "TSecs": 745,
        "CMsgs": 284,
        "Alt": 35000,
        "GAlt": 35189,
        "InHg": 30.1092529,
        "AltT": 0,
        "Call": "ACA394",
        "Lat": 47.86931,
        "Long": -72.90211,
        "PosTime": 1672216731064,
        "Mlat": false,
        "Tisb": false,
        "Spd": 513.0,
        "Trak": 117.2,
        "TrkH": false,
        "Type": "B38M",
        "Mdl": "Boeing 737MAX 8",
        "Man": "Boeing",
        "CNum": "61217",
        "From": "YYC Calgary, Canada",
        "To": "YHZ Halifax / Stanfield, Canada",
        "Op": "Air Canada",
        "OpIcao": "ACA",
        "Sqk": "1144",
        "Help": false,
        "Vsi": 0,
        "VsiT": 0,
        "WTC": 2,
        "Species": 1,
        "Engines": "2",
        "EngType": 3,
        "EngMount": 0,
        "Mil": false,
        "Cou": "Canada",
        "HasPic": false,
        "Interested": false,
        "FlightsCount": 2,
        "Gnd": false,
        "SpdTyp": 0,
        "CallSus": false,
        "Trt": 2,
        "Year": "2018"
    }, {
        "Id": 12601386,
        "Rcvr": 1,
        "HasSig": false,
        "Icao": "C0482A",
        "Bad": false,
        "Reg": "C-GBIN",
        "FSeen": "\/Date(1672215747131)\/",
        "TSecs": 984,
        "CMsgs": 5124,
        "Alt": 32925,
        "GAlt": 33185,
        "InHg": 30.1801186,
        "AltT": 0,
        "Call": "ROU1689",
        "Lat": 45.119546,
        "Long": -71.834575,
        "PosTime": 1672216731191,
        "Mlat": false,
        "Tisb": false,
        "Spd": 462.5,
        "Trak": 31.1,
        "TrkH": false,
        "Type": "A319",
        "Mdl": "Airbus A319 114",
        "Man": "Airbus",
        "CNum": "845",
        "From": "FLL Fort Lauderdale Hollywood, United States",
        "To": "YQB Quebec Jean Lesage, Canada",
        "Op": "Air Canada Rouge",
        "OpIcao": "ROU",
        "Sqk": "1447",
        "Help": false,
        "Vsi": -2112,
        "VsiT": 0,
        "WTC": 2,
        "Species": 1,
        "Engines": "2",
        "EngType": 3,
        "EngMount": 0,
        "Mil": false,
        "Cou": "Canada",
        "HasPic": false,
        "Interested": false,
        "FlightsCount": 1,
        "Gnd": false,
        "SpdTyp": 0,
        "CallSus": false,
        "Trt": 2,
        "Year": "1998"
    }, {
        "Id": 10812570,
        "Rcvr": 1,
        "HasSig": false,
        "Icao": "A4FC9A",
        "Bad": false,
        "Reg": "N420LA",
        "FSeen": "\/Date(1672215081608)\/",
        "TSecs": 1650,
        "CMsgs": 4226,
        "Alt": 34000,
        "GAlt": 34281,
        "InHg": 30.2007866,
        "AltT": 0,
        "Call": "LAE2512",
        "Lat": 46.00371,
        "Long": -71.20912,
        "PosTime": 1672216731894,
        "Mlat": false,
        "Tisb": false,
        "Spd": 399.0,
        "Trak": 210.7,
        "TrkH": false,
        "Type": "B763",
        "Mdl": "Boeing 767 316F/W",
        "Man": "Boeing",
        "CNum": "34627",
        "Op": "MAS Air Cargo",
        "OpIcao": "MAA",
        "Sqk": "0706",
        "Help": false,
        "Vsi": 0,
        "VsiT": 0,
        "WTC": 3,
        "Species": 1,
        "Engines": "2",
        "EngType": 3,
        "EngMount": 0,
        "Mil": false,
        "Cou": "United States",
        "HasPic": false,
        "Interested": false,
        "FlightsCount": 1,
        "Gnd": false,
        "SpdTyp": 0,
        "CallSus": false,
        "Trt": 2,
        "Year": "2006"
    }, {
        "Id": 12706028,
        "Rcvr": 1,
        "HasSig": false,
        "Icao": "C1E0EC",
        "Bad": false,
        "FSeen": "\/Date(1672196473179)\/",
        "TSecs": 20258,
        "CMsgs": 1605,
        "Alt": 125300,
        "GAlt": 125300,
        "AltT": 0,
        "Call": "TEST1234",
        "Tisb": false,
        "TrkH": false,
        "Sqk": "",
        "VsiT": 0,
        "WTC": 0,
        "Species": 0,
        "EngType": 0,
        "EngMount": 0,
        "Mil": false,
        "Cou": "Canada",
        "HasPic": false,
        "Interested": false,
        "FlightsCount": 4,
        "Gnd": false,
        "SpdTyp": 0,
        "CallSus": false,
        "Trt": 1
    }],
    "totalAc": 5,
    "lastDv": "638077811342841157",
    "shtTrlSec": 30,
    "stm": 1672216731909
}
```

I am trying to loop and have the data for every loop in the nesty structure
As depending on the plane info, data is often changed fopr more or less inside nesty loop
I have tried everything on my low knowledge of coldfusion
Need some help and many thanks to all

Comment: Mike can I request you ask a more focused question (and one that is semantically valid). You have a JSON *string* there and yer asking how to loop over it as a struct: that doesn't make any sense. Also I think yer requirement is a bit vague: looping over a struct to access specific properties of it? Not how one does that. Next time, start with some code, and the question should be along the lines of "given this code, I am expecting x but I am getting y". The way you are phrasing your question is more "write my code for me", not "help me solve this problem with my code [which is here]".

Answer (score 2):

Save it as a variable, then deserialize.

`<cfset JSONObject = DeserializeJSON(YourVariable)>`

You can then call specific key-values from it like `#JSONObject.flgH#`.

If you have multiple to loop through you can output it with array notation, like `#JSONObject.acList.Reg[1]#` - you would replace the number with a variable like `[i]` if you're looping through it dynamically.

Comment: As a newbie can I have the code example.. all I want is the acList node and the number of node in that key acList

Comment: That is good now I have to total number of flights : 
<cfoutput>
  #JSONObject.totalAC#
</cfoutput> 

How can I get the loop from acList to have the info about each plane

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I am trying #JSONObject.acList.Id[1]# but it doesn't work
If I try your example #JSONObject.acList.Reg[1]# still give me an error

Answer (score 2):

You can start with:

```
<cfset local.stData = deserializeJSON(whatever that variable is holding the JSON) />
<!--- Now, local.stData.acList is what is called "an array of structs" --->
<cfloop array="#local.stData.acList#" index="local.n" item="local.stPlane">
    <!--- In here, you can work with local.stPlane.id, for example --->
    <!--- If you need to loop over the "keys" of the struct, like "Id", "Rcvr", you can do that, too. I prefer structKeyList --->
    <cfloop list="#structKeyList(local.stPlane)#" index="local.sKey">
        <cfif local.sKey = 'Id'>
        <cfelseif local.sKey = 'Rcvr'>
        </cfif>
        <!--- Or... --->
        <cfswitch expression="#local.sKey#">
            <cfcase value="Id">
                
            </cfcase>
            <cfcase value="Rcvr">

            </cfcase>
            <cfdefaultcase>
                <!--- For unexpected keys, or just skip this block --->
            </cfdefaultcase>
        </cfswitch>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```